# Error in this XML: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix` in this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/connected" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The error is in `<ImageView>`.
What could be the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put the namespace declaration `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in the root element of your layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your need to define the xmlns attribute in the topmost element, in this case, the LinearLayout tag.